# Simple LINQ DataTable Aggregation Doesn't Work

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable, data-manipulation

So I have a dataset like this:

```
Group   Value
A       1
A       2
B       2
B       5
```

Simply I just want to have:

```
Group   Value
A       3
B       7
```

as another DataTable variable. Here is my C# code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using utilityClass;

namespace testData
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string path = "test_data.csv";
            bool isFirstRowHeader = true;
            dt = Utils.GetDataTableFromCsv(path, isFirstRowHeader);

            var results = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                          group row by row.Field<string>("Group") into grp
                          select new
                          {
                              Id = grp.Key,
                              sum = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Value"))
                          };
            DataTable newDataTbl = results.CopyToDataTable();
        }
    }
}
```

It gives me error in CopyToDataTable() saying:

[image]

Does anyone know what goes wrong in my codes? Thanks!

Comment: Please, post you CopyToDataTable method implementatio. The problem is that your aggregate function is using an anonymous type, and when you try to call the CopyToDatatable method, it can't cast the anonymous type to a concrete type. to better help with the problem, post your method

Comment: @Stormhashe The OP is using the [`CopyToDataTable` extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189(v=vs.110).aspx) provided by the framework. The problem is that extension requires a collection of `DataRow` objects as the input.

Comment: Ahh I understand, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit of slight of hand you can create a datarow collection in the `from` statement by using a where statement to assign the ItemArray of a datarow object and checking if it's null.  Something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string path = "test_data.csv";
    bool isFirstRowHeader = true;
    dt = Utils.GetDataTableFromCsv(path, isFirstRowHeader);
    var results = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                  group row by row.Field<string>("Group") into grp
                  let dr = dt.NewRow()
                  where (dr.ItemArray = new object[] { grp.Key, grp.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Value")) }) != null
                  select dr ;
    DataTable newDataTbl = results.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You result is  not a sequence of `DataRows`. `CopyToDataTable()` is only available on `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is or derives from `DataRow` (more info in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921(v=vs.110).aspx)).
There is a solution for this, as you can see in the quoted [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921(v=vs.110).aspx). To do that you are going to need to implement this workaround which is based using reflection:

[How to: Implement CopyToDataTable Where the Generic Type T Is Not a DataRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096(v=vs.110).aspx)